# How to stop a return after a function processes (Prevent HTML from not loading)

Tags: php

Hello I have a function that checks if my registration details doesn't match in the database, if it does, then return the code.

But every time I return the code, my HTML won't load because it's stopping it from loading.
I want the HTML to be always under the PHP code, for some specific reason (I want the errors to display up to the form, and not under).

This is an example of my function:

```
function check_available($name, $password, $email)
{
    global $pdo;

    $check_user = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :username LIMIT 1");
    $check_user->execute( array(':username' => $name) );        

    $check_email = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = :email LIMIT 1");
    $check_email->execute( array(':email' => $email) ); 

    $error = '';
    if ($check_user->rowCount())
    {
        $error .= 'Username already exists!';
        return handle_errors($error);
    }
    else if($check_email->rowCount() && !$check_user->rowCount())
    {
        $error .= 'Email already exists!';
        return handle_errors($error);
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $check_in = check_available($name, $password, $email);


        if ($check_in == true)
        {
            echo 'Created account sucessfully!';
        }
    }
?>  
<html>
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br />
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

**After submiting, (with having a username that already matches in database), the HTML will hide & error will display.**

*How do I prevent this? is there a trick for that?*

Comment: Atleast someone is using PDO.

Comment: PDO is a really good method to manage databases, I started using it not just because MySQL_* is outdated, it is easier to manage multiple queries, connections, more secure and makes more sense. Really love PDO.

Comment: I am thrilled http://images.t-nation.com/forum_images/1/5/15fc7_ORIG-the_rock_clap_clap_gif.gif

Comment: as a matter of fact, mysql_* is easier to manage connections (you don't need it at all), it is no less secure than PDO and multiple queries occurs too rare to talk about.

Comment: That's true, @YourCommonSense. But, security is security.

Answer (score 3):

There is no point in hiding a form.
Quite contrary, form have to be shown to let a user enter another name.

So, just add an error output to your form - that's all you need

Edit
looks like it's handle_errors() function to blame.

```
function reg_has_errors($name, $password, $email)
{
    global $pdo;

    $error = '';

    $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE user_name = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute( array($name) );        
    if($stm->rowCount())
    {
        $error .= 'Username already exists!';
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute( array($email) );        
    if($stm->rowCount())
    {
        $error .= 'Email already exists!';
    }
    return $error;
}

$errors = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $errors = reg_has_errors($name, $password, $email);

    if (!$errors)
    {
        echo 'Created account sucessfully!';
    }
}
echo errors;
```

Comment: I don't want to hide my form, after the function will return; , the form will get hidden, I want to prevent this!

Comment: Maybe your code is generating some secret-hidden-ninja error.

Comment: Also, make a try block on your statement call maybe it will show you the path of glory.

Comment: Maybe you should redirect them to another page on success?